# Issue Importing Class in Android Studio

Tags: java, class

I'm encountering an issue while trying to import a class in my Android Studio project. I have a Usuario class located in the datos package, and I'm trying to import it into my RegistrarseActivity class.

Project Structure:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTHhB.png)

```
/app
    /java
        /datos
            Usuario.java
        /com.example.tradehub.activities
            RegistrarseActivity.java
```

Problem:

When I try to import the Usuario class using import datos.Usuario;, it's showing in red and the compiler cannot find the class.

What I've Tried:

Ensured that the Usuario.java file is in the correct package (package datos;).
Checked package structure and verified that Usuario.java is located in the datos package.
Reviewed IDE settings related to project structure, modules, and dependencies.